# C - Passing pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Can somebody tell me why this code does not work? I tried to compile and run it  with gcc 6.3, but the result of the printf is a kind of memory mess: "P@" instead of "something". Compiling it with gcc 5.3 on https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler, gives me the exact result ("something").

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *vari;

void foo(char **ts)
{
    char buffer[] = "something";
    *ts = &buffer[0];
}

int main (void)
{
    foo(&vari);
    printf("vari: %s\n", vari);
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior, `buffer` doesn't exist any more once you leave `foo()`.

Comment: Duplicate link 1: why this doesn't work. Duplicate link 2: why you can't rely on it even if it "seems to work". Duplicate link 3: why it would work if you declared it as a pointer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifetime of `buffer` will end once the function `foo` returns because it has automatic storage duration. This will make the behavior of your program undefined.
You can allocate memory dynamically which has static storage duration

```
void foo(char **ts)
{
    char *buffer= malloc(10);
    strcpy(buffer, "something")
    *ts = &buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: ...noting that it's then the responsibility of the caller to `free` that memory.

Comment: @Bathsheba; Yes, in the caller function of course.

Answer (score 3):

`buffer[]` has *automatic storage duration*.

Using a pointer that's set to its address in the caller to that function will result in undefined behaviour.

It would have been a different matter had you written

```
static const char* buffer = "something";
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior. Accessing a automatic storage lifetime element outside it's scope can result in *anything*.

When the `foo()` function ends the memory of `buffer` is deallocated.

There are different ways you can solve the issue thought

- Make the `buffer` of static storage duration.
- Allocate memory and then copy the literal `"somehting"` to it and assign it to `*ts`.